# Integration of pandas dataframe yields an array with a different length. How to store this in the same dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I have a pandas dataframe, e.g.

```
    x  y
0   0  3
1   1  3
2   2  2
3   4  3
4   5  4
5   7  3
6   8  1
7  10  2
```

Now I want to calculate the integral of these values for each data point using `scipy.integrate.cumtrapz`. If I run

```
>>> cumtrapz(df.x,df.y)
array([  0. ,  -1.5,   1.5,   6. ,   0. , -15. ,  -6. ])
```

I get the values I want, but I can't insert it into the dataframe:

```
>>> df["z"] = cumtrapz(df.x,df.y)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/steen/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3044, in __setitem__
    self._set_item(key, value)
  File "/home/steen/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3120, in _set_item
    value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
  File "/home/steen/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3768, in _sanitize_column
    value = sanitize_index(value, self.index)
  File "/home/steen/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 747, in sanitize_index
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Length of values (7) does not match length of index (8)
```

Because, as can be seen above, the length of the output array is one less than the original dataframe.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Use `cumtrapz(df.x,df.y, initial=0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Scipy docs address this issue here:

[scipy.integrate.cumtrapz](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.cumtrapz.html)

**Quote:**

---

initial : scalar, optional

If given, uses this value as the first value in the returned result. Typically this value should be 0. Default is None, which means no value at x[0] is returned and res has one element less than y along the axis of integration.

---

**Example:**

```
cumtrapz(df.x,df.y, initial=0)
```

**Output:**

```
array([  0. ,   0. ,  -1.5,   1.5,   6. ,   0. , -15. ,  -6. ])
```